# Load color asset from custom bundle in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, bundle

I am attempting to load a color asset from a custom bundle I created.  (Essentially just created a folder and added .bundle to the end).  It appears the code to find the bundle works just fine, but I can't actually extract anything (more specifically colors) out of my bundle.  They simply all return nil.

Here is my code..

```
    guard let bundleURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "TestTheme", withExtension: "bundle") else { return }
    guard let bundle = Bundle(url: bundleURL) else { return }
    let color = UIColor(named: "NavigationBarTint", in: bundle, compatibleWith: nil)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = color
```

as for the contents of my bundle, I created a color asset in XCode and added a few colors.  Went to the asset's location in Finder and just copy/pasted the asset into my bundle.  So all that exists in my 'TestTheme' bundle is a single color asset with 4 colors, one of them being the NavigationBarTint.

Is there some step I'm missing here?  All other research seems to point to this being all thats required but I'm getting all nil values.

Thanks

Comment: May be you can use UserDefault and store your color or you can directly use UIColor(named: "Image Name").

Answer (score 1):

just create a folder in assets, name it as you like, right-click -> `New Color Set`, set your color inside the color set, name the color set as you like(e.g. "**Custom_Green**"). to load the color just call it as `let customGreen = UIColor(named: "Custom_Green")`. that's it. easy. Also if you want a color for light mode and a color for dark mode you just change the `Appearances` to `Any, Dark` set the colors and you're good to go.

Comment: For reason's i won't bother to explain right now, this needs to be in a separate bundle and not the main bundle.  But regardless, thats exactly what im doing here in my new bundle but it doesnt work.

Comment: Did you find solution to it yet?

Answer (score 1):

Occasionally I also get `nil` returned from `UIColor(named:in:compatibleWith:)` even though I'm 100% sure the colour is defined in the asset catalogue and the name is correct.

When this happens to me, a `Product > Clean Build Folder` does the trick.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe [this could help you](https://dev.to/silviaespanagil/step-by-step-customize-your-colors-in-swifui-o98) the idea is to add the colors in the asset and after that to create a public extension for Color

```js
 static let orange = Color("CustomOrange")
 static let yellow = Color("CustomYellow")
```

This way you can use later Color.orange or Color.yellow and they will take the custom color you have set on

Comment: It's a Swift Question not SWIFTUI.